# How to see which ports Firefox is using in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, firefox, internet, osx-lion, download

Which ports is Firefox using in Mac OS X?

I particular, which parts are being used for downloads, and what is the speed of traffic on each of these ports?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a native command from OS X terminal:

```
tcpdump -i [interface, en0 is ethernet, en1 is wireless]
```

It's a good idea to redirect command output to a file or search it with `grep`
The second option is to use [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) or similar applications (most of them are under payment so I haven't mentioned them).